# object *name* has no method *method name*

Tags: javascript

I have two objects: `command` and `topic`.

`topic` has a method `actions` that is called from `command`.

When `topic.actions()` is called, there are no errors.

When I use the object property `command.taxonomy` whose value is the string `'topic'` to call `topic.actions()`, an exception is thrown: `"Object topic has no method actions"`.

**Why would the console report `topic` has no method `actions` when it is right there?**

```
command = {
    /*this is set when an html element is clicked by another function:
        for this example, it equals the string 'topic'*/
    taxonomy : '',

    //this is called when the same html element is clicked as above
    taxonomy_actions: function(){
        this.taxonomy.actions();
    }
}

topic = {
    actions:function(){
        //returns an array of valid commands for topic
        this.commands.push('shortcuts');
        this.commands.push('action_list');
        this.commands['shortcuts'] = new Array();
        this.commands['action_list'] = new Array();

        for(x in this.aliases){
                this.commands.action_list.push(this.aliases[x]);
                this.commands.shortcuts.push(x);
        }   
        return this.commands;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the actual calling code in here - I have no idea what "When I use the parameter command.taxonomy whose value is the string 'topic' to call topic.actions()" means.

Comment: So, `taxonomy` is the string `'topic'`?  Strings don't have an `actions()` method.  I think you want to set `taxonomy` to the *object* `topic`, not a string.

Comment: @Rocket: good suggestion, and in my opinion, correct.  The error message I was receiving makes perfect sense now.  I assigned the actual taxonomy object to a property of my command object and I have access to the properties I want from the taxonomy objects.

Comment: @ChrisTavares: I edited the question.  I meant 'property' when I said 'parameter'.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually mostly there in your question:

> whose value is the string 'topic' to call ...

What you want is to access the 'topic' property of the Object that contains the topic{} object.

Therefore you want:

```
taxonomy_actions: function(){
    containing_object[this.taxonomy].actions();
}
```

The containing object (if you didn't attach topic to something) would be `window` in browser environments or `global` in NodeJS.